# JS click in a Jquery function on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS function that I want to automatic click in a jquery.click link when page loads.

How can I make it work?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yv44ppvp/)

When page loads I want to see the alert, no click in the link needed.

**js**:

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementsByClassName("c").click();
}


$(".c").click(function(){
    alert("ok");
});
```

**html:**

```
<a href="#" class="c">test</a>
```

Comment: you need to attach `click` event before  use of `trigger`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `attach click` event before  `trigger` event.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yv44ppvp/3/)

Change

```
document.getElementsByClassName("c")
```

to

```
document.getElementsByClassName("c")[0]
```

Use Below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".c").click(function(){
         alert("ok");
      });
 });

 window.onload = function(){
      document.getElementsByClassName("c")[0].click();
      // Or use jQuery trigger 
      // $(".c").trigger('click') 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yv44ppvp/1/)**

<kbd>**[trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**</kbd> `click` on `document.ready`

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $(".c").click(function(){
        alert("ok");
    });
    $('.c').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Trigger event right after you create handler

```
$(function(){
    $(".c").click(function(){
        alert("ok");
    }).click();
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yv44ppvp/2/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".c").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can push your alert into a function :

```
function callAlert() {
   alert('a');
}
```

And you can change the event click like this :

```
$(".c").click(callAlert);
```

Finally you can call the alert function when page loads like this :

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    callAlert(); // call here
});
```

---

**Code :**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    callAlert(); 
    $(".c").click(callAlert);
});

function callAlert() {
    alert('a');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node.
>
> To assign a `click` handler, either you will have to iterate through `nodelist` or just assign event to first `element`

Try this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName("c")[0].click();
};
$(".c").click(function () {
    alert("ok");
});
```